# Getting Calendar events with microsoft-graph-client

Tags: azure, vue.js

I managed to get the access_token via the oauth2 API,

But then when I try to retrieve access to the events I get the following error:

statusCode: 400, code: "BadRequest", message: "Current authenticated context is not valid for thi…OAuth 2.0 implicit flow for single-page web apps."

I've created a Vue Component and this is the function that returns the token :

```
getToken: function() {
  var self = this;
  var params = new URLSearchParams();
  params.append('client_id', self.client_id);
  params.append('client_secret', self.client_secret);
  params.append('grant_type', self.tokenSettings.grant_type);
  params.append('resource', self.tokenSettings.resource);
  var url = self.tokenSettings.url;
  axios.post(url,
      params, {
        withCredentials: false
      })
    .then(function(response) {
      self.access_token = response.data.access_token;
      self.token_type = response.data.token_type;
      self.expires_in = response.data.expires_in * 1000;
      self.isAuthenticated = true;
      self.getEvents();
      window.setInterval(function() {
        self.getToken();
      }.bind(self), response.data.expires_in * 1000);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      self.isAuthenticated = false;
    });

}
```

And below is the function I am tryig to get the events with but the returns the error above:

```
getEvents: function() {
  var self = this;
  var apiUrl = '/me/events';
  if (self.access_token) {
    // Create a Graph client
    var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
      authProvider: (done) => {
        // Just return the token
        done(null, self.access_token);
      }
    });
    client
      .api(apiUrl)
      .select('*')
      .orderby('createdDateTime DESC')
      .get((err, res) => {
        console.log('res', res);
        if (err) {
          console.log('error:', err);
          self.isAuthenticated = false;
        } else {
          self.events = res.value;
        }
      });
  } else {
    self.isAuthenticated = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: `params.append('client_secret', self.client_secret);` Please do not use client secrets from front-end JavaScript code. It is your app's password and is now public.

Comment: In production mode you won't see it. Will you?

Comment: It makes no difference. If the secret is used in front-side code it is visible.

Comment: You need to use implicit flow (as the error says). I'd advise checking out ADAL.JS.

Comment: If the implicit flow means having the user redirected to the login page and redirected back with the token in the query string. I have done that and it works fine. But I want the app to work without the user having to interact with it.

Comment: That is a back-end flow then, you can't do things as the app in a front-end securely.

Comment: can you point me to the right documentation? I can't find what I need.

Comment: Check out the AAD developer guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code. You can also find code samples from under Reference -> Code samples.

Comment: This API still redirects the user to the login page. I don't want that. I have implemented that already. My next step is to get the vue component to get the access-token and retrieve the events without a user having to log in first. Is that even possible?

Comment: Your Vue front-end cannot do that. You'll need a back-end which can do client credentials grant flow or use a refresh token to get a user-specific token.